# NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/appengine/api/urlfetch/ResponseTooLargeException

Tags: java, google-app-engine, maven, google-api, google-api-java-client

I am using Google + API to search for people using the following statement.

```
  Plus plus = new Plus.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, null).
            setApplicationName("AppName").setGoogleClientRequestInitializer(new 
            PlusRequestInitializer(API_KEY)).build();

  Plus.People.Search searchPeople = plus.people().search(personName).setMaxResults(1L);

  PeopleFeed peopleFeed = searchPeople.execute();
```

I put the dependencies for the library in pom.xml so that it can be build when maven executed

```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
       <artifactId>google-api-services-plus</artifactId>
       <version>v1-rev64-1.13.2-beta</version>
   </dependency>
```

But I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/appengine/api/urlfetch/ResponseTooLargeException
    at com.google.api.client.extensions.appengine.http.urlfetch.UrlFetchTransport.buildGetRequest(UrlFetchTransport.java:61)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:867)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:399)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:328)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:449)
    at com.google.PeopleSearch.googleAccountSearch(PeopleSearch.java:52)
    at com.google.Search.main(Search.java:128)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.ResponseTooLargeException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: This class is part of the appengine sdk jar, try cleaning the project and check you've correctly added the sdk dependency

Comment: This usually happens, if you user the incorrect transport in the google API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a similar error *NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/appengine/api/urlfetch/HTTPMethod* , for me it was resolved by copying the App Engine SDK jar file from `SDK/lib/user/appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.9.27.jar` into my project's `WEB-INF/lib` folder (I was not using Maven).